# No wi-fi detected in Windows 7 in boot camp partition

Tags: wifi, bootcamp, windows

I've installed Windows 7 on a Boot Camp partition on a 2013 Macbook Air. However when booted into Windows 7 no wi-fi network can be detected. The Mac partition is fine. A Google search indicates this is a widespread problem but I can't seem to find a solution. Any help?

Comment: sorry but u did that using wich os?

Answer (score 4):

Sorry about this but I've solved the issue. I went back to the external hard drive I had onto which Boot Camp had downloaded the Windows 7 drivers during the installation process. I had to manually activate the application found in Bootcamp/Drivers/Broadcom/BroadcomWirelessWin7x64. Hopefully this will be helpful to someone else.